# HttpContext.Current.Response.Filter: Response filter is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net

Busy with some legacy code to write to csv/xls:

```
// Set up response
string filename = "ErrorControlExport";
string attachment = "attachment; filename=" + filename + "_" + DateTime.UtcNow.ToFileTime() + "." + extension;
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = contentType;
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");
// Clear any settings (such as GZip)
HttpContext.Current.Response.Filter = null;//exception occurs here

// Add BOM to force recognition of UTF-8
byte[] bom = new byte[] { 0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf };
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(bom);
```

However when the code reaches:

```
// Clear any settings (such as GZip)
HttpContext.Current.Response.Filter = null;//exception occurs here
```

it throws a `HttpException` of

> Response filter is not valid.

So my questions are:

1) How do I set the filter to an empty or default filter?

2) Is it even necessary?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Check this [post](http://romsteady.blogspot.com/2008/12/workaround-aspnet-response-filter-is.html). Even though it talks about ASp.Net 3.5,  I tried it and it works. I just read the `var filter = Response.Filter` and then assigned null to it `Response.Filter = null`

Comment: @Nilesh +1 also saw it though because Im using a newer version didnt think it would apply but seems it does! Please set comment as answer so i can mark it as such

Answer (score 11, accepted):

check this [post](http://romsteady.blogspot.com/2008/12/workaround-aspnet-response-filter-is.html). Even though it talks about ASp.Net 3.5, I tried it and it works. I just read the filter `var filter = Response.Filter` and then assigned null to it `Response.Filter = null`

Comment: +1... Sorry it has taken so long to accept just been really busy!

Answer (score 2):

Besides @Nileshs' comment/answer (+1 to it as I used this method)

Another option is to create an Empty filter:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates and empty filter for HttpResponse.Filter (i.e no proessing is done on the text before writting to the stream)
/// </summary>
class EmptyFilter : MemoryStream
{
    private string source = string.Empty;
    private readonly Stream filter;


    public EmptyFilter(HttpResponse httpResponseBase)
    {
        this.filter = httpResponseBase.Filter;
    }


    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        this.source = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);

        this.filter.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.source), offset, Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(this.source));
    }
}
```

than simply set to:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Filter = new EmptyFilter(HttpContext.Current.Response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try clean your solution and delete old DLL's (maybe left over from a project rename). That sorted it for me.